# I don't understand a line of code in an SPI driver

Tags: c, pointers, casting, spi

```
uint32_t data;

SPDR = ((uint8_t*) & data)[x];
```

I can see what this line does - it can be put in a for loop to read each byte of "data" into `SPDR`, but I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: SPI bus is only 8-bits wide, so to send 32-bits you need to send it in parts. Depending on endianess, you send it in forward or reverse.

Comment: What exactly you don't understand? `SPI` mechanism or `C` code?

Answer (score 3):

Lets split it up into its separate parts:

- `&data` gives you a pointer to `data`, the type is `uint32_t *`
- `(uint8_t*)` turns that `uint32_t` pointer into a pointer to `uint8_t` (or an array of unsigned bytes)
- The indexing takes one of the bytes in the "array"

If you put it in a loop, it takes one byte at a time from the four-byte `uint32_t` value, and assigns it to `SPDR`.

Comment: Thanks for you help, Joachim, but I'm still having trouble with this. Take the following:

Answer (score 1):

As StackOverflow's [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spi/info) says

> Serial Peripheral Interface (SPI) is a serial, synchronous, full
>   duplex bus commonly used in embedded systems. It is most often used
>   for communication between a microcontroller and peripheral hardware
>   such as memories, shift registers, sensors, displays etc, but can also
>   be used for MCU to MCU communication.
>
> Transmissions normally involve two shift registers of some given word
>   size, such as eight bits, one in the master and one in the slave; they
>   are connected in a ring. Data is usually shifted out with the most
>   significant bit first, while shifting a new least significant bit into
>   the same register. After that register has been shifted out, the
>   master and slave have exchanged register values. Then each device
>   takes that value and does something with it, such as writing it to
>   memory. If there is more data to exchange, the shift registers are
>   loaded with new data[1] and the process repeats. Transmissions may
>   involve any number of clock cycles. When there is no more data to be
>   transmitted, the master stops toggling its clock. Normally, it then
>   deselects the slave. **Transmissions often consist of 8-bit words**. A
>   master can initiate multiple such transmissions if it wishes/needs.
>   However, other word sizes are also common, such as 16-bit words for
>   touchscreen controllers or audio codecs, like the TSC2101 from Texas
>   Instruments; or 12-bit words for many digital-to-analog or
>   analog-to-digital converters.

```
SPDR = ((uint8_t*) & data)[x];
```

will result in a cast of `uint32_t` pointer into a pointer to `uint8_t` - that is pointer to 8-bits. Pointer arithmetic is based on a pointer type, and array subsripting is based on pointers arithmetic

---

C Standard n1124 **§** 6.5.2.1/2 Array subscripting

A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted
designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator []
is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that
apply to the binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2] designates the E2-th
element of E1 (counting from zero).

---

so indexing the array will move a pointer about sizeof (*pointer), thus 1 byte. This way you can traverse all 4 bytes in 32 bit thing.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is 4-bytes, `(uint8_t*) & data` is converting it to a pointer of 1-byte values, `x` which you haven't shown, is indexing into the 1-byte array of values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still having problems with this. Take the following:

```
uint16_t EN_A_WrRd_OP16(uint8_t opcode,uint16_t write_data)
{
    uint16_t read_data;
    uint8_t i;

    EN_A_CS_Low();
    SPIC_DATA=opcode;
    while (!(SPIC_STATUS&SPI_IF_bm));
    for (i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        SPIC_DATA=((uint8_t*)&write_data)[i];
        while (!(SPIC_STATUS&SPI_IF_bm));    
        ((uint8_t*)&read_data)[i]=SPIC_DATA;
    }
    EN_A_CS_High();
    return read_data;        
    }
```

Going round the loop twice to read SPIC_DATA, it reads 0x34 then 0x12. However, on exiting the loop, read_data contains 0x0000!
If I do it the “long” way and replace the loop with the following:

```
    SPIC_DATA=write_data;
    while (!(SPIC_STATUS&SPI_IF_bm));
    read_data=SPIC_DATA;
    SPIC_DATA=write_data>>8;
    while (!(SPIC_STATUS&SPI_IF_bm));
    read_data|=SPIC_DATA<<8;
```

it works correctly i.e read_data returns with the value 0x1234.